# How to untar all .tar.gz with shell-script?

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I tried this:

```
DIR=/path/tar/*.gz

if [ "$(ls -A $DIR 2> /dev/null)" == "" ]; then
  echo "not gz"
else
  tar -zxvf /path/tar/*.gz -C /path/tar
fi
```

If the folder has one tar, it works. If the folder has many tar, I get an error.

How can I do this?

I have an idea to run a loop to untar, but I don't know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
for f in *.tar.gz
do
  tar zxvf "$f" -C /path/tar
done
```

Comment: just in case you want to skip parent directories  `code`  --strip-components=NUMBER
       strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction `code`

Answer (score 14):

I find the `find` exec syntax very useful:

`find . -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar -xzvf {} \;`

`{}` gets replaced with each file found and the line is executed.

Answer (score 3):

```
for a in /path/tar/*.gz
do
    tar -xzvf "$a" -C /path/tar
done
```

### Notes

- This presumes that files ending in `.gz` are gzipped tar files. Usually `.tgz` or `.tar.gz` is used to *signify* this, however `tar` will fail if something is not right.
- You may find it easier to `cd /path/tar` first, then you can drop the `-C /path/tar` from the untar command, and the `/path/tar/` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer worked for me with a slight modification

```
for f in *.tar.gz
do
  tar zxvf "$f" -C \name_of_destination_folder_inside_current_path
done
```

I had to change the forward slash to a backslash and then it worked for me.

Comment: I can only assume this is a Windows-specific workaround; it doesn't provide a significantly different solution to the problem as asked.

Comment: @chepner You're right. I was working on Windows.